# How to set the width and height of a Raphael JS rectangle based on the lines of text it contains?

Tags: javascript, size, raphael

I am creating a rectangle element which I want to later use as a tooltip on an SVG circle element. Right now, I am trying to think of some logic to set the height and width of the rectangle element which should change according to the lines of text it contains.. I am simply creating a Raphael text element and translating it on the rectangle so that it appears as if the rectangle 'really' contains the text. (This is because I am not supposed to use any third-party tooltip plugin, neither can I create a  and modify it using jQuery. Neither can I use gRaphael. I am supposed to use only Raphael rectangle element as the tooltip.)

Here's what I am doing -

```
var tipText = "Asoo ok m ml palksksk feesf k\nWeek:X-VAL\nRank:Y-VAL";
//splitting tipText for "\n"
var tipText_seperate = tipText.split("\n");
var tipText_seperate_len = tipText_seperate.length;

var line_len = [];
for(var i=0;i<tipText_seperate_len;i++){
 line_len[i] = tipText_seperate[i].length;  
}

var a = Math.max.apply(Math, line_len);//getting the length of largest line

//setting the width and height of the rectangle
var box = {};
box.width = (a*5)+5;
box.height = tipText_seperate_len*25;

var c = {};
c.x = 10;
c.y = 10;
c.r = paper.rect(c.x,c.y,box.width,box.height,5).attr({fill:'#000000', opacity:0.7});
c.t = paper.text(c.x,c.y,tipText).attr({fill:'#FFFFFF'});
c.t.transform("t"+box.width/2+","+box.height/2);
```

Now the size of rectangle gets adjusted for some lines of text, while for some it doesn't. In that case I have to change the value of box.width which does not seem correct. Is there any efficient and logically correct way to achieve this? Please Help...

Comment: In general, it's MUCH better to use absolutely positioned divs for tooltips -- takes care of all the wrapping and so forth. But so long as you insist on using Raphael, the answer from amustill is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to create the text element and use `getBBox` to get the bounding box of the text element, which provides the dimensions as well as `x` and `y` values.

Here's an example and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FRtrP/2/).

```
// Create Raphael and circle set
var Paper = new Raphael('canvas', 300, 300),
    circles = Paper.set();

// Add circles to canvas, setting the tooltip text as a
// data attribute
circles.push(
    Paper.circle(100, 150, 25).data('tooltip', 'Here is some text'),
    Paper.circle(200, 150, 25).data('tooltip', 'And here is \nsome longer text')
);

// Some base styles
circles.attr({
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 0
});

// Positioning of the tooltip box
var margin = 10,
    padding = 5;

// Hover functions
circles.hover(
    // On hover, create and show tooltip
    function() {
        // If the tooltip already exists on the element, simply
        // show it. If it doesn't then we need to create it.
        if (this.tooltip && this.tooltip.box) {
            this.tooltip.show();
            this.tooltip.box.show();
        } else {
            // Get the x and y positions.
            // We get the 'true y' by deducting the radius
            var x = this.attr('cx'),
                y = this.attr('cy') - this.attr('r');

            // Create the tooltip text, attaching it to the
            // circle itself
            this.tooltip = Paper.text(x, y, this.data('tooltip'));

            // Calculate the bounding box of our text element
            var bounds = this.tooltip.getBBox();

            // Shift the text element in to correct position
            this.tooltip.attr({
                // At this point `y` is equal to the top of the
                // circle arc. When creating a text element, the
                // `x` and `y` values are center points by default,
                // so by deducting half the height we can fake
                // a bottom align. Finally deducting our `margin`
                // value creates the space between the circle and
                // the tooltip.
                y: y - (bounds.height / 2) - margin,
                fill: '#fff'
            });

            // Create the tooltip box, again attaching it to the
            // circle element.
            //
            // The `x`, `y` and dimensions are dynamically calculated
            // using the text element's bounding box and margin/padding
            // values.
            //
            // The `y` value again needs some special treatment,
            // creating the fake bottom align by deducting half the
            // text element's height. We then adjust the `y` further
            // by deducting the sum of the `padding` and `margin`.
            // The `margin` value is needed to create space between
            // the circle and the tooltip, and the `padding` value
            // shifts the box a little higher to create the illusion of
            // padding.
            //
            // Try adjusting the `margin` and `padding` values.
            this.tooltip.box = Paper.rect(bounds.x - padding, bounds.y - (bounds.height / 2) - (padding + margin), bounds.width + (padding * 2), bounds.height + (padding * 2));

            // Style the box and put it behind text element
            this.tooltip.box.attr({
                fill: '#000',
                stroke: 0
            }).toBack();
        }
    },
    // On hover out, hide previously created tooltip
    function() {
        // Hide the tooltip elements
        this.tooltip.box.hide();
        this.tooltip.hide();
    }
);​
```

Comment: thanks a million for the solution and demo.. it is working and i find it to be an extremely efficient way to create tooltips.. I am not able to understand a couple of line though.. Please explain me the meaning of following lines..  1. The y-coordinate of the text element:      y: y - (bounds.height / 2) - margin  2. The y - coordinate of the rectangle box:      bounds.y - (bounds.height / 2) - (padding + margin)  I guess I am getting confused wit hthe concepts of padding, margin, height.. Thanks once again :)..

Comment: @anujit I've edited by answer and demo with more commenting to explain these two lines.